# Install Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi 2 Model B

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation, raspberrypi

I am using Windows 7 on a regular PC. I tried to install Ubuntu on a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B and it didn't work. I downloaded Win32DiskImager utility and ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi2, wrote on the SD card, and then I got the attached screen and I don't know how to continue.

[after pressing CTRL+ALT+F2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeaev.jpg)

[the guide I found with the user and password..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECm5h.png)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that screen - you installed the Ubuntu Server image to the RPi and that's the login screen (and where it spits out notices).  You enter your username, and then your password after you hit enter, and it drops you to a command line prompt.  Were you expecting something else?

Comment: how do I know the user and password? I try few things but it didnt go wwll..
Do I need internet connection for the first run?

Comment: The defaults would be listed on the site or instructions where the download was located.

Comment: this is the place where it shows the password and user:
https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/raspberry-pi-2/

I will upload video in a few minutes to show the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The login prompt appears before the boot process is complete, so you ended up with a screen like this in which the boot messages continue *after* the Ubuntu Server login prompt:

[image: IMG:]

Sometimes when this happens you can wait until the boot messages stop and you get a blinking cursor, and then just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and get a fresh login prompt. If that doesn't work, try to login again from a new virtual console.

1. Open a virtual console (tty) by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.
2. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you still can't login, run the command: `sudo reboot` from the console, and maybe you will get a working login prompt the next time when the Raspberry Pi reboots.

Comment: have all that..